# Need to get type value of maximum messageid

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to get `type` value of which has maximum value of `messageid` from table `mesaj_mesajlar`. I grouped too by `type` for show you.

My query:

```
SELECT
   mesaj_konular.id AS topicid,
   mesaj_mesajlar.id AS messageid,
   mesaj_mesajlar.tip AS type,
   uyeler.ad AS uname
FROM mesaj_konular 
INNER JOIN uyeler ON uyeler.id = mesaj_konular.uid 
INNER JOIN mesaj_mesajlar ON mesaj_mesajlar.konuid = mesaj_konular.id
GROUP BY 
   topicid,
   type
```

Table:

```
topicid     messageid   type    uname
1           1           0       x
1           2           1       x
2           20          0       x
3           15          0       x
3           17          1       x
```

result should be:

```
topicid     messageid   type    uname
1           2           1       x
2           20          0       x
3           17          1       x
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this is to get the `MAX()` of type for each topicid:

```
SELECT
   mesaj_konular.id AS topicid,
   mesaj_mesajlar.id AS messageid,
   mesaj_mesajlar.tip AS type,
   uyeler.ad AS uname
FROM mesaj_konular 
    INNER JOIN uyeler ON uyeler.id = mesaj_konular.uid 
    INNER JOIN mesaj_mesajlar ON mesaj_mesajlar.konuid = mesaj_konular.id
    INNER JOIN (
           SELECT konuid, MAX(tip) MaxTip
           FROM mesaj_mesajlar 
           GROUP BY konuid
    ) max_mesaj_mesajlar ON mesaj_mesajlar.konuid = max_mesaj_mesajlar.konuid 
          AND mesaj_mesajlar.tip = max_mesaj_mesajlar.MaxTip
GROUP BY 
   topicid
```

Comment: @algkmn -- np, glad I could help!